# Java joda api not working

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I have used Joda date api in my project but it seems either I have done something wrong or Joda api is not returning me what i intend to get.
I want to get the difference in hours and minutes between two dates.

### Here is my code

```
Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy").parse("05/18/2009");
Date date2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("05/18/2007");
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(date1);
DateTime d2 = new DateTime(date2);
Period p = new Period(d1, d2);
long minutes = p.getMinutes();
long hours = p.getHours();

System.out.println("hoursBetween-----"+minutes+"-----minutesBetween------"+hours);
```

I get output 0 and 0 in both minutes and hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getMinutes()` doesn't return the number of minutes. It returns the minutes part of the period.

The period between these two dates is -2 years, 0 month, 0 week, 0 day, 0 hour, 0 minute, 0 second.

If you want the number of hours and the number of minutes between two dates, use

```
Hours.hoursBetween(d1, d2).getHours()
Minutes.minutesBetween(d1, d2).getMinutes();
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2009, 5, 18, 0, 0);
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2007, 5, 18, 0, 0);

```
        Period period = new Period(d2, d1);
        PeriodFormatterBuilder HHMMSSFormater =
                new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendHours().appendSeparator("-").appendMinutes().appendSeparator("-").appendSeconds();
        System.out.println(period.getYears());
        System.out.println(period.getMonths());
        System.out.println(period.getDays());
        System.out.println(period.getHours());
        System.out.println(period.getMinutes());
```

Please try this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this -

```
DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2009, 5, 18, 4, 0);
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2007, 5, 18, 0, 30);

            Period period = new Period(d2, d1);
            PeriodFormatterBuilder HHMMSSFormater =
                    new PeriodFormatterBuilder().appendYears().appendSeparator("-").appendMonths().appendSeparator("-")
                    .appendDays().appendSeparator("-").appendHours().appendSeparator("-").appendMinutes().appendSeparator("-").appendSeconds();
            System.out.println(HHMMSSFormater.toFormatter().print(period));
```